# bug in guessing number game

Tags: php

I am trying to build a game , but its not working properly

It's supposed to prompt me to `"Make your $guess..."`, but it only gives `"I'm going to think of numbers between 1 and 10 (inclusive). Do you think you can guess correctly?"`

This was the specification:

> PHP Number Guessing
>
> "In this project, you’ll create a number guessing game. Your program
> will generate a random number between 1 and 10. You’ll run the game 10
> times and tell the user some information about their guessing
> abilities."

```
$play_count = 0;
$correct_guesses = 0;
$guess_high = 0;
$guess_low = 0;
echo "I'm going to think of numbers between 1 and 10 (inclusive). Do you think you can guess correctly?\n";

function guessNumber()
{
  global $play_count,$correct_guesses,$guess_high,$guess_low;
 
  $play_count++;
  $num =  rand(1,10);

  echo "\nMake your $guess...\n";
  $guess = intval(readline(">>"));
  //$guess = intval($guess);

  echo "Round: $play_count \n my number: $num, \nYour guess: $guess";
    
  if ($guess === $num) {
    $correct_guesses++; 
  }

  if ($guess > $num) {
    $guess_high++;
  }

  if ($guess < $num){
    $guess_low++;
  }

  echo guessNumber(10);
  echo guessNumber(12);

  $percent_correct = $correct_guesses/$play_count * 100;

  echo "\nAfter $play_count rounds, here are some facts about your guessing:\nYou guessed the number correctly $percent_correct% of the time.\n" ;

  if ($guess_high > $guess_low){
    echo "When you guessed wrong, you tended to guess high.";
  } else  {
    echo "When you guessed wrong, you tended to guess low." ;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to give us more context as to what is not working. Like error messages for example.

Comment: it suppose to prompt me to "\nMake your $guess...\n", but it only gives "I'm going to think of numbers between 1 and 10 (inclusive). Do you think you can guess correctly?

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: A good place to start would also be to format your code with consistent indentation to make it more human-readable.  When you do that, do you find that you're defining a function but then never invoking it?

Comment: $guess = intval(readline(">>")); should give me prompt "\nMake your $guess.>> to guess a number but it doesn't appear on the terminal

Comment: @deda: Perhaps, but first you'd need to *call your function* somewhere.  Add `guessNumber();` at the very end of the script.  Which really just makes this little more than a typo.  (Though it's also worth noting that your function calls itself, unconditionally.  Which will make it infinitely recursive.  You *probably* don't want that.)

Comment: 7PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: guess in /home/ccuser/workspace/php-number-guessing/index.php  how to define $guess here ?

Comment: Is that from `echo "\nMake your $guess...\n";`? Always tell us which line threw the error. In that line, surely you don't want a `$` there to make it into a variable? you want it to literally show the word "guess", don't you??

Comment: P.S. No idea what you think these lines are for: `echo guessNumber(10);
  echo guessNumber(12);`? guessNumber doesn't return anything you could echo, and doesn't accept any input arguments. And also as someone pointed out earlier, this will cause an infinite loop because the function will always keep calling itself. Just remove them.

Comment: What your code seems to be completely lacking is a control loop where you count the number of rounds, and ask the user to guess again if the number of rounds has not reached the desired maximum.